# Tomcat not running on Amazon EC2, Redhat Instance

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm a java application developer, and don't know much about linux configuration.

I'm trying to install Java and Tomcat to a fresh Redhat instance on Amazon EC2, and executed the below script.

```
mkdir /usr/local/java
cd /usr/local/java
curl http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u2-b13/jdk-7u2-linux-i586.rpm > jdk.rpm
rpm -iv jdk.rpm

updatedb; locate javac | grep bin  # this step merely serves to verify the installation
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java 100
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/jar 100
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/javac 100
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
updatedb

mkdir /env
mkdir /env/tomcat
cd /env/tomcat
curl http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.23.tar.gz > apache-tomcat-7.0.23.tar.gz
tar zxvf apache-tomcat-7.0.23.tar.gz
cd apache-tomcat-7.0.23
bin/startup.sh #
```

At this point, http://ec2-23-20-24-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/ was expected to return Tomcat homepage, but it didn't :(

```
cd /etc/rc.d/init.d/
vi tomcat
```

I pasted the below content to the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tomcat init script for Linux.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 96 14
# description: The Apache Tomcat servlet/JSP container.

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
CATALINA_HOME=/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23
export JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME

exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh $*
```

Then executed:

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat
chkconfig --level 2345 tomcat on

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02
export CATALINA_HOME=/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23

/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/bin/shutdown.sh
/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/bin/startup.sh
```

Nowhere did I get any error, but I also couldn't get the Tomcat homepage to display.
Can you guide where where I went wrong.

Thanks
James

**EDIT:**

Tomcat log (on stopping and starting server)

```
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:06:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 530 ms
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ROOT
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 18, 2012 2:08:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 583 ms
```

**EDIT2:**

My problem looks similar to the one on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=59937, but that provides no solution.

I performed a wget, and I received a proper index.html with Tomcat homepage html.
    wget http://ec2-23-20-24-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080

I have two security groups - default and quick-start-1, and I've added ports 80 and 8080 to the list.

Comment: Have you checked the tomcat log files? Maybe it didn't start correctly?

Comment: I just checked it. It seems to stop/start properly. Log above (EDIT)

Comment: What did the browser say? 404? 500? Connection error? Do you have any firewall on this machine, preventing access to port 8080?

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-23-20-24-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com" URL: http://ec2-23-20-24-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: I have added access to ports 80 and 8080 in the security groups. But that doesn't change anything :( Added EDIT2 above.

Comment: If you got the index page using wget isn't it ok? Or was that from the machine running tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with help from AWS Support:

> Hello
>
> It initially looks like iptables is running on your instance, my checks show filtered ports, you will need to add a rule to allow port 8080, or disable the firewall on the instance itself.
>
> You can verify this by running as root "`service iptables stop`" and then see if you can connect on port 8080.
>
> Kind Regards
>     AndyC

Link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=312167&#312167